# Class method returning dictionary error

Tags: class, vba

My class "Contact" has following fields:

```
Private Name As String
Private CurDate As Date
Private Dict As Dictionary

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set Dict = New Dictionary
End Sub
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set Dict = Nothing
End Sub
```

(Should this be in constuctor `Set Dict = New Dictionary`?) And following get property for dictionary field:

```
Public Property Get Get_Dict() As Dictionary
    Get_Dict = Dict
End Property
```

Now in my code I have:

```
Dim Contact1 As New Contact
Contact1.Set_Contact x, y, z

Dim TempDic As New Dictionary
Set TempDict = Contact1.Get_Dict
```

It dosen't compile: "Argument is not optional". How is it possible if I clearly have no arguments in Get_Dict property?

Comment: This line `Contact1.Set x, y, z` cannot be right.  It implies that you have a public sub or function named `Set` in your contact class.  `Set` is a VBA keyword so you cannot use it as the name of a procedure.

Comment: In get–dict you need to use Set to return Dict (because its an object).  You don't need to instantiate TempDict (so remove the New there), because you're assigning that from your class.

Comment: @mwolfe02 you're right, it is just a typo.

Comment: @TimWilliams, thanks! I always forget about Set for objects. But maybe you know if I should write 'Set Dict = New Dictionary' in 'Class_Initialize()' when I use object variable as a field for class? Or by default compiler will initialize a class variable the same way?

Comment: @grozhd - no, the compiler will not assign a default value to your object variables: you have to do that yourself. `Class_Initialize` is a good place to do that.

Comment: @Tim Williams, thanks! Should I post an answer myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have used:

```
Public Property Get Get_Dict() As Dictionary
   Set Get_Dict = Dict
End Property
```

As we assigning the reference to an object.